# Credit Card Transaction script fails webdriver, if another window is opened manually

Tags: firefox, transactions, selenium-webdriver, credit-card

I am executing credit card transaction script through webdriver. So there is form where the details are to be filled and then click on “Submit” button to perform successful transaction. 
Here, transaction script gets executed on firefox browser, and in between if another browser say Safari is opened manually, then transaction script which is getting executed on firefox through webdriver, it gets fail

Environment : WebDriver 2.43, 
Firefox Version: 32.0

Please correct me, if i am performing anything wrong

Comment: Is it something that, the web driver script gets disturb by anyway if other window is opened ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is, you need to switch to new window from initial window and then perform some operation and switch back to your initial window.

To know how to switch between windows, watch this video.[How to switch between multiple browser windows using webdriber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugAPaofq1nQ)

Comment: But, y do i need to switch between multiple windows, i don't face any such issues, while executing any other test scripts. This happens only while performing this particular credit card transaction.